# currentTimeMillis() not returning expected result

Tags: android

In my application, I need to parse a JSON that includes the end time of an event. When this event is in progress, I need to calculate the time left for the finalization of that evet. To do this I use this piece of code:

```
// I get the time and convert it from millis to seconds
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;                      
techsTime.add((int) (queue.event.get("event0").endtime - end));
```

Once I've the time in seconds, I convert it to d,h,m,s. This is working like a charm in some devices like the Optimus Black and the HTC Desire. But today I've tested my app with the ZTE Blade of a friend and the time left of the event is very strange. It appears in negative numbers and digits very distance from the original ones. I've tested the app with different values and there's no pattern, they're like random numbers, e.g:

Optimus Black -> 21m 32s 
ZTE Blade -> -38m -57s

I've thought that System.currentTimeMillis() could be different in both devices, but both of them are using CM7 as OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the clock of one of the devices not set properly. With the time extracts you give it seems like the difference is exactly one hour, which might be a cause of wrong clock setting. When you consider the time set, also take a look at the time zone. It might be that both devices show the same time, but one of them is configured in different time zone.

It will be very weird for modern device not to sync its clock in the net, but still possible for ZTE for example.

Comment: The problem is that my app is used almost worldwide... I'm gonna check the time zone of both devices...

Comment: You were righ! It was the time zone! The problem now is what I said before, my app is used worldwide, that means different time zones... Maybe checking the time zone of the phone and doing the necessary operations? Any other idea?

Comment: No time zone itself is not a problem, because you calculate absolute time (time since epoch). The problem will occur if one of your devices does not calculate this correctly

Comment: @KrLx_roller - just fix the clock of the devices. When they are set to be correct everything will be all right even when you have users all over the world. 1PM in CET is 2PM in EET and they will happen in the same moment in time. This means that their time since epoch will be the same and thus the `getTime` method for the two will return the same. This is why we use the universal time since epoch, so that we do not get confused in the different time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.nanotime()` - it is specially created in order to measure the time between 2 events.
`System.currentTimeMillis()` uses the system clock which does **not** update every 1 millisecond and thus is unreliable and giving different results.

Comment: I'll try it and I'll tell you something!