# Strange IllegalArgumentException related to delay parameter in TimerTask, Android

Tags: java, android, timertask

```
myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTaskForListChecker, 0L, timerInterval*1000);
```

Above line "sometimes" somehow throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal delay to start the TimerTask: -1543808998843
    at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:567)
    at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:528)
    ...
```

As you see, I have "0" in my delay parameter (later I try changing it to 0L but it didn't work too)

How can it see the value "0" as "-1543808998843"?

**Update 1:**

I have the following line and I never change timeInterval variable.

```
private int timerInterval = 3 * 60;
```

**Update 2:**
I found out that, the system which generates this exception, also returns a negative number (overflows?) for the following line:

```
(int)((double)System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L)
```

Can it be related to customized Android os? (by companies - device specific - factory default)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that the `period` parameter is wrong.  And the most likely cause of an unexpected negative number in a situation like this is integer overflow.

My guess is that you've declared `timerInterval` as an `int` and "sometimes" you try to delay for a couple of million seconds ...

---

You say that this returns a negative number on some platforms:

```
    (int)((double)System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L)
```

That is bizarre!  It is either a bug in the port of Android to that platform, or somehow the system clock has been set to the incorrect value.

The `currentTimeMillis` value is *supposed* to be the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 ... as a 64-bit signed value.  I don't see how you can get a negative number from the expression above unless `currentTimeMillis()` is returning a bogus value negative value.

Possibly related:

- [currentTimeMillis() not returning expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077716/currenttimemillis-not-returning-expected-result)
- http://andrea.levinge.me/android-get-current-time-in-milliseconds/

Comment: I checked it now, I only have this line: "private int timerInterval = 3 * 60;" and I never change it anywhere.

Comment: I suggest that you modify your code to print out the actual values of the parameters when the exception is thrown ... or examine them with a debugger.

Comment: the problem is I don't get this exception but "some" users get it. I see these from remote exception logs. Please see update-2 in my question; may it help?

Comment: I tried to set date to year 1970 of my Android 4.0.3 tablet (the same device with one of the users having this exception), so I could recreate this exception but I couldn't. It produces valid values. I am out of ideas :/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone has a similar issue.

I had this exact same problem and I have realized that the date on the device was somehow reseted to 1920. Changing it back solved the issue.